# Check if url is open in inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, inappbrowser

In my app i want to an webpage open a inappbrowser. The webpage i want to open have three sites. The first which is opened with a link to the second site. The second site with a link to the third side.

How can i check if the third page was opened on the inappbrowser and set then an value in local storage. I found a solution but its only to get data from the first page.

Better it would be if i can pass any data from the third page to Cordova app.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Something like (if "third.html" is shown in appbrowser get var $data from it)

Answer (score 2):

To check if a page is opened in inappbrowser, you can check navigator.userAgent.

By default, userAgent of inappbrowser contains "cordova".

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("cordova") !== -1) {
  // do something here
}
```

and to pass value from inappbrowser to cordova app, you can refer to below link:

http://www.telerik.com/blogs/cross-window-communication-with-cordova's-inappbrowser